# Passing dynamic feature using karate framework

Tags: dynamic, karate

Through karate i want to run a scenario where i have kept my payload in a json file and i am passing multiple values to the same scenario using another json file. For example : @setup Scenario: * def payloadvalue = read("classpath: src/resource/data/payloadvalue.json") Scenario outline: login using mutiple userid userid :  Given url baseurl * def requestfile = read("classpath:src/resource /loginuser.json) And request requestfile When method post Then status 200 Examples: |userid| |karate.setup().payloadvalue| Under resource folder i have the json file which looks like Payloadvalue.json [ {"userid": "123abc"}, {"userid": "456efg"}, {"userid": "789hgt"} ] Payload.json { "username": "mehta12", "userid" : "${userid} ", "DOB" : "12/01/2000", "Gender" : "Male" }
On running the scenario my payloadvalue file is not getting read and no value is passed. In log i cam see the request passed is as below
{ "username": "mehta12", "userid" : "${userid} ", "DOB" : "12/01/2000", "Gender" : "Male" }

but it didn't worked for me. Seems something is wrong in my case. Help is really appreciated Not sure what mistake i am doing

Comment: sorry you are trying to do too much without understanding the basics of karate. I suggest you get a hard-coded json to work before trying to use json-files. also learn how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and make sure read the docs and look at other questions first: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+setup+loop

Comment: Actually i am running the karate scenario using hard code json since long. While copy pasting the question here it seems everything got mixed@setup 
Scenario: 
* def payloadvalue = read("classpath: src/resource/data/payloadvalue.json")

 Scenario outline: login using mutiple userid userid : <userid>
 Given url baseurl
 * def requestfile = read("classpath:src/resource /loginuser.json) And request requestfile
 When method post 
Then status 200 
Examples: 
|userid| 
|karate.setup().payloadvalue| 
Under resource folder i have the json file which looks like

Comment: Payloadvalue.json 
[ 
{"userid": "123abc"},
 {"userid": "456efg"}, 
{"userid": "789hgt"} ] 

Payload.json
 { "username": "mehta12",
 "userid" : "${userid} ", 
"DOB" : "12/01/2000", 
"Gender" : "Male" } 

On running the scenario my payloadvalue file is not getting read and no value is passed.
 In log i can see the request passed is as below
 { "username": "mehta12", 
"userid" : "${userid} ",
 "DOB" : "12/01/2000", 
"Gender" : "Male" } 
 Seems something is wrong in my case. Help is really appreciated Not sure what mistake i am doing

Comment: first of all I don't think `${}` will work in karate. second, please edit your question because it is badly formatted (read the links please) - if you really want help, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - for now, I pass - hopefully someone else can help you here